# How can I remove cropping for images in woocommerce orders email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce crops the ordered items' images.

How can I remove this?

Most of my images are on portrait mode.

I looked around online but it seems that the cropping fixes are only for front end.

Tried the code below but it only changes the size but still crops the image.

```
function my_email_order_items_args( $args ) {
$args['show_image'] = true;
$args['image_size'] = array( 150, 150 );

return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', 'my_email_order_items_args', 10, 1 );
```

After I order how can I remove cropping ang just have a fixed height and auto width?

EDIT:

I tried the suggestion below but it seems add image size does not work:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', 'filter_item_thumb', 10, 2);
function filter_item_thumb($image, $item){
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size('email_orders', 120);
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce', array(
        'thumbnail_image_width' => 200,
        'gallery_thumbnail_image_width' => 100,
        'single_image_width' => 500,
        ) );
    $itemObject = $item->get_product();
    $image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail($itemObject->get_id(), 'medium_large'); // use your image size
    // you can add_image_size() to specify your uncropped thumbnail

    return $image_url;
}
```

Comment: did you try passing both `($order, $args)` to your function and add_filter with `10, 2` ?

Comment: Yes but to no avail it still crops image. I think the $order does not have anything to do with the cropping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the `$args['image_size']` just kind of specifies the width of the image, but it's always going to be a square cropped.  So instead, you can filter the `order_item_thumbnail` which is called in the email.  If you `add_image_size` and specify an uncropped image size that you want to use for this... replace `medium_large` with that size and you should be good.

```
function my_email_order_items_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_image'] = true;
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', 'my_email_order_items_args', 10, 1 );

add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', 'filter_item_thumb', 10, 2);
function filter_item_thumb($image, $item){

    $itemObject = $item->get_product();
    $image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail($itemObject->get_id(), 'medium_large'); // use your image size
    // you can add_image_size() to specify your uncropped thumbnail

    return $image_url;
}
```

Comment: Thank your code worked but I cannot get the image Size Running Ill edit the post to see what happened

Comment: You have to add a custom image size. Then you will most likely need to regenerate thumbnails.

Comment: Ohhh I see! Since they are not yet uploaded with that size! I cannot do that Since they already have the images up and running is there a smaller image size I can use?

Comment: I would create a custom one. Using add__image_size that suits your needs. Then use this https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ if this answer helps you please accept it.